# Phantom Mercurial, How to remove?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm trying to install TortoiseHg on Ubuntu 14.04. It went fine, but trying to open it complains about having an unsuported Mercurial version (3.4.1). I removed via:

- sudo apt-get remove mercurial
- sudo apt-get purge mercurial
- sudo dpkg -r mercurial
- sudo dpkg --purge mercurial

It comes out as successful, but if I try:

```
hg --version
```

I get:

```
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 3.4.1)
(see http://mercurial.selenic.com for more information)

Copyright (C) 2005-2015 Matt Mackall and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Any other ideas? TortoiseHG needs 3.1.x or 3.0.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out where in your path an application exists using the `type` command like this (when using bash):

```
ry4an@four:~$ type -a hg
hg is /usr/local/bin/hg
```

It's possible it was installed as a python package in which case the command would be:

```
pip uninstall mercurial
```

but it might just be easier/safer to install a version that is supported somewhere that comes earlier in your path so Tortoise find that one.